# Is it possible to convert data in a queried data?

Tags: google-sheets

> QUERY(otherSheets!A:B, "SELECT A B")

By using this line, I can get a temporary table that has two columns, A and B. Is it possible to add another column C, to the table by functions without showing it in a sheet and then manually editing it?

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your intention is to manually add data side-by-side with formula results. This exposes you to the risk of rows getting misaligned.

You probably should insert the new column to the existing data table instead of adding it to formula results.

See this thorough [treatment of the row misalignment issue](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/95901649).